# Asp .Net Core client side custom validation not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm trying to implement client side validation for a custom attribute but it seems to not be working.

ToleranciaSuperior cannot be greater or equal than ToleranciaInferio.  Server Side the check is working correctly, however client side it is not. What am i missing?

```
public class Geometria
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Componente { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, float.MaxValue)]
    [Display(Name = "Tolerância Inferior")]
    public float ToleranciaInferior { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, float.MaxValue)]
    [ToleranciaLessOrEqualThan("ToleranciaInferior", ErrorMessage = "Tolerância Superior tem de ser maior que a Tolerância Inferior")]
    [Display(Name = "Tolerância Superior")]
    public float ToleranciaSuperior { get; set; }

}

public class ToleranciaLessOrEqualThanAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
{
    private readonly string _comparisonProperty;

    public ToleranciaLessOrEqualThanAttribute(string comparisonProperty)
    {
        _comparisonProperty = comparisonProperty;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        ErrorMessage = ErrorMessageString;
        var currentValue = (float)value;

        var property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_comparisonProperty);

        if (property == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Property with this name not found");

        var comparisonValue = (float)property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);

        if (currentValue <= comparisonValue)
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        var error = FormatErrorMessage(context.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName());
        context.Attributes.Add("data-val", "true");
        context.Attributes.Add("data-val-tolerancialessorequalthan", error);
    }
}
```

Comment: The client side validation requires javascript files. Perhaps some files are not included or loaded.

Comment: they were, i just missed the part where you have to add the method to $.validator